# Internet Explorer compatibility broken by this javascript/jquery snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, compatibility

Sorry if this post seems lazy, but I really have no idea how the following snippet of code is breaking Javascript in my site!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
$('.opcion').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color','#FFF');
},function(){
    $(this).css('color','rgb(200,200,200)');
});
$('body ul li').each(function(){
    var tamcompleto = $(this).height() + 'px';
    $(this).hover(
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({height:tamcompleto},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
        },
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
        }
    );
    $(this).css('height','50px');
}); 
$('.comunicate').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var center   = 'height=436,width=465,top='+((screen.height - 436)/2)+',left='+((screen.width - 465)/2);
        var address = 'comunicate.php?fid='+$(this).attr('id');
        window.open (address,'comunicate', center); 
    });
});
$('.objeto').each( function(){
    $(this).click(function() {
        var center   = 'height=380,width=900,top='+((screen.height - 380)/2)+',left='+((screen.width - 900)/2);
        var address = $(this).attr('id');
        window.open (address,'Verarticulo', center); 
    });
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor','rgb(255,122,79)');
    },function() {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor','rgb(200,200,200)');
    });
});
$('.elastica img').each(function(){
    $(this).css('width','100px');
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({width: 200}, 150);
    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({width: 100}, 150);
    });
});
$('.elastica').click(function(){
     $('#imgampliada').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
$('.icon').hover(function(){
    var newwidth = $(this).attr('data-width');
    $(this).find('img').mousemove(function(e){
        var newposition = e.pageX - newwidth/2;
        $('#choice').html($(this).attr('id'));
        $('#choice').stop(false, true).animate({width: newwidth, left: newposition}, 200);
    })
}); 
$('#iconwrapper').mouseout(function(){
    $('#choice').html('');
    $('#choice').stop(false, true).animate({width: 0}, 100);
});
 });

function popup(mylink, windowname)
{
if (! window.focus)return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
   href=mylink;
else
   href=mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
return false;
}
```

Does anybody with more experience in IE compatibility for javascript have any idea whats wrong? The page runs flawlessly in FF and Chrome; but doesn't load any javascript in IE. This is driving me crazy!!

Comment: _"but doesn't load any javascript in IE"_ - what do you mean "doesn't load"? Doesn't run? I don't see any obvious issues, so if you can't use IE's debugging tools for some reason you could always narrow the problem down by resorting to the old faithful method of deleting/commenting a little bit at a time (say one `.each()` at a time) until it starts working.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Some more information on exactly how it doesn't work would help..

Comment: any errors in the console? (try hitting F12 in IE)

Comment: The only issue I can see at naked eye is that you're not using brackets... not really an issue but ugly anyways. Can you post your js and html in jsfiddle so we can find where the bug is in a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Just double check that the value you are you are passing to `popup()` for `windowname` doesn't have a space in it. IE doesn't like it when `window.open()` uses spaces.